# UITableViewCell Custom Cell set text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to set the text of a custom cell that inherits from `UITableViewCell` with my own method, here's my code:

```
- (void)updateCell {
    NSIndexPath* indexPath;

    indexPath= [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1];
    Somecell *cell = (Somecell *)[mytblview cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.b_freq.text = @"12332123";
    [mytblview reloadData];         
}
```

This code is not updating my `UITableView` as well. Are there any mistakes in my code or do you suggest using a different method?

Comment: What is `brQ`? You need to call reloadData on your tableview `mytblview`.

Comment: Are you using IB? Did you set the IBOutlet?

Comment: no,all pure the code, he case is i want set cell.bfreq.text after i got it from uitextfield without nsmutablearray as buffer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement the `UITableViewDataSource` delegate method yourself rather than calling it and then modifying the cell that is returned:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    if (indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 0) {
       Somecell *cell = [[Somecell alloc] init];
       cell.b_freq.text = @"12332123";
       return cell;
    }
}
```

Implement the method and then return the cell that you want.

Check out the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) for more info.

Comment: i know that... but i want to update text on row number x for example, i've put the text within indexpath as number of row, but when i reload it, nothing change :)

Comment: the case is  i want set cell.bfreq.text after i got it from uitextfield without nsmutablearray as buffer..

Comment: When you reload the table's data, is it calling your code in cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: no its calling updatecell first then reload the whole table, i follow this tutorial http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862193/changing-text-color-in-custom-uitableviewcell-iphone but not working

Comment: Right, but when you reload the table it will be calling into the available implementation of tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:. If you've implemented this yourself then it should be using the cells that you return from here. In your updateCell implementation you modify the cell but your call to reloadData is causing the cells to be regenerated...throwing away the modified cell and replacing it with a new one returned by cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: so it no need to reload?

Comment: ah done.. no need to reload it :) thanks :).. i've try it 3 days and it works when it not reloaded :)